# Initialize component after display css class change

Tags: angular

I have tabs component. I'm adding
'style.display' : 'block' when tab is active (visible) and 'none' when it is hidden.

In components that are displayed in each tab I'm hiding button when height of one of the other element is less than e.g. 100 px;
I'm doing it using :

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
 const wrapper = this.elRef.nativeElement?.querySelector('.wrapper');
 const height = wrapper?.offsetHeight ?? 100;

 if(height <= 100) {
   this.renderer.setStyle(this.button.nativeElement, 'display', 'none');
 }

}
```

It is working fine for tab that is currently visible on the screen - I mean when I select the tab and refresh the page button is hidden, but for other tabs components wrapper's height is = 0 because those tabs have 'display' set to 'none'. All components displayed in the tabs are initalized at once.

The question is :
What should I do to re render the view when I change the tab ?

Answer (score 0):

You can reload the parent component by placing this method on tab changes.

```
this._document.defaultView.location.reload();
```

To perform this, you should have injected _document in the constructor:

```
constructor(
@Inject(DOCUMENT) private _document: Document) {
```

}
This will rerender the view.